# Why am I getting the wrong formula for the area of a dodecagon?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polygons

More likely than not, I'm just making a simple algebraic mistake, but I can't seem to find it and so I would like some help.

Divide a (regular) dodecagon into $12$ congruent isosceles triangles with the length of the equal sides being the apothem $r$. The angle formed by two equal sides is equal to $30°$. Why, then, does the formula

$A = 12 \cdot r^2 \cos(15°) \sin(15°) =3r^2 \neq  12 \left(2-\sqrt{3} \right) r^2$ fail?

Comment: Where does $2-\sqrt3$ come from?

Comment: Are you perhaps mixing up apothem and diameter? Because connecting the apothems (apotha? apothoi?) to the center would give you a few quadrilaterals

Comment: @SteveKass That is the correct formula, whereas mine is incorrect(or so I think).  Note the $\neq$. To answer your question, I am getting it from Wiki.

Comment: The apothem and the circumradius are not equal.

Comment: @SteveKass ohhh okay. I see. That was where I was confused. I guess I just got the terminology mixed up. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the apothem (the length of a segment from the center of the dodecahedron to the midpoint of a side, or equivalently the radius of the inscribed circle) and the circumradius (the distance from the center to a vertex) are not equal. The area of a dodecahedron is $3R^2$, where $R$ is the circumradius, and $12(2-\sqrt3)r^2$ where $r$ is the apothem.

Answer (score 0):

The apothem of a regular $n$-gon inscribed in a circle with radius $r$ is equal to
$$r\cos\frac\pi n.$$

Here we have
$$\cos\frac\pi{12}=\cos\Bigl(\frac\pi3-\frac\pi4\Bigr)=\frac{\sqrt 2(\sqrt 3+1)}4.$$